Non-orientable real algebraic three-dimensional manifolds
Smooth real algebraic hypersurfaces of even degree in $\mathbb{RP}^4$ that are maximal (i.e. that are homologically as rich as possible in the sense of the Smith-Thom inequality) are all non-orientable (see Section 1.2 in $\textit{Mutual position of hypersurfaces in projective space}$, O. Viro ).
I am trying to investigate the possible topological types and geometries of such hypersurfaces, but all the sources about 3-dimensional manifolds I browsed reduce to the orientable case and say that analogue results can be proven in the non-orientable with some adjustments. Do you know where I could find precise statements on this topic ?
In particular, I am looking for

the analogue of the prime decomposition and of the torus decomposition for non-orientable closed three-dimensional manifolds;
some general information about families of known examples (Seifert manifolds, analogues of Haken manifolds, ...);
the proof of a statement that can be found in the introduction of $\textit{Non-orientable 3-manifolds of complexity up to 7}$, G. Amendola, B. Martelli without reference: "Among the $8$ three-dimensional geometries, only $5$ have non-orientable representatives.".


Which specific results are you asking about? "On this topic" would cover over 100 years of development of 3-dimensional topology.

It is not clear what topological or geometrical features are relevant to the problem I'm looking at.
At this step, I am looking for analogues of the classical decomposition theorems,
and maybe a survey of the specific properties of the non-orientable manifolds from the main families of examples we know. Also, I read that only five out of the eight geometries could be realized by non-orientable manifolds, but I have not been able to find the origine and the proof of this statement.

Maybe the question is quite wide (I didn't vote to close). If this is really new to you, one important idea of proving "non-orientable" statements using "orientable" ones is the orientation double cover https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientability#The_orientation_double_cover.

Can you give a reference for the statement in the first paragraph of the question?

Regarding non-orientable prime three-manifolds, this answer might be of interest to you.


The prime decomposition theorem is slightly different for non-orientable 3-manifolds. There is a version decomposing along 2-spheres described in Hempel’s book, but there is a subtle flaw in the statement corrected by Bruce Trace.  A possible more natural decomposition is along projective planes and 2-spheres, but here the prime summands may be orbifolds with isolated orbifold points which are the cone over a projective plane. However I’m not sure if this is written down somewhere.

As pointed out by Moishe Kohan, the geometric decomposition for non-orientable 3-manifolds is described in the last section of Scott’s “The Geometries of 3-manifolds”. Unfortunately this doesn’t seem to have been proved in full generality yet.

Classes of examples of non-orientable 3-manifolds may be made by taking mapping tori either of non-orientable surfaces or of non-orientable mapping classes of orientable surfaces. Note that if $M$ is closed, aspherical, and non-orientable, then $b_1(M)>0$ and $M$ is Haken. Another simple way to construct non-orientable manifolds is to take a complement of a tubular neighborhood of a knot and attach the boundary to a torus by a double cover where the meridian wraps twice and the longitude once.

There are no closed non-orientable 3-manifolds modeled on spherical, Nil, or $\widetilde{SL_2(\mathbb{R})}$ geometries. Manifolds modeled on these geometries are Seifert fibered with non-triviald Seifert bundle. If a Seifert fibered manifold is non-orientable, then the Euler class of the Seifert bundle of the two-fold orientable cover is zero (since there is an orientation-reversing involution either reversing the orientation of the fibers or the base), so the manifold cannot be modeled on one of these geometries.



I think Peter Scott in "Geometries of 3-manifolds" defines prime decomposition along projective planes so that orbifolds with isolated singularities appear naturally.

You should probably also add a reference to Meeks and Scott "Finite group actions on 3-manifolds" which implies a JSJ decomposition for nonorientable Haken manifolds.

There is a (slightly) less abstract proof that the “twisted Seifert geometries” (elliptic, Nil, and PSL) have no non-orientable manifold quotients.  First show that orientation-reversing isometries of $S^3$ have fixed points.  Next show that all isometries of Nil and PSL preserve orientation.  This is discussed in Peter Scott’s article “The geometries of 3-manifolds”.
